# Java: Two objects that use each other

Tags: java, class, object, recursion

There's a problem I can't solve. I have simple part of code here:

```
public class Item{
    Block blockDrop;

    public void setBlockDrop(Block block) {
        this.blockDrop = block;
    }
}

public class Block{
    Item itemDrop;

    public void setItemDrop(Item item) {
        this.itemDrop = item;
    }
}

public class ItemDirt extends Item {
    public ItemDirt() {
        setBlockDrop(Registry.blockDirt);
    }
}

public class BlockDirt extends Block {
    public BlockDirt() {
        setItemDrop(Registry.itemDirt);
    }
}

public class Registry {
    public static ItemDirt itemDirt = new ItemDirt();
    public static BlockDirt blockDirt = new BlockDirt();
}
```

When I run this, blockDirt WILL drop itemDirt, but itemDirt WON'T drop blockDirt. Is there any way I can solve this? I could instead add to Registry constructor:

```
itemDirt.setBlockDrop(blockDirt);
blockDirt.setItemDrop(itemDirt);
```

but that defeats whole simplicity of my objects.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your code, as your declare the class Item two times (but not the class Block) - so I guess the first class is actually Block and not Item

Comment: `public class Item() {` how come this is legal

Comment: Whoops. I that was typo when I was copying the code. I will fix that now. But the problem still remains.

Comment: Isn't the first class Item and the second class Block?

Comment: Do you have this code in one single file? Because its not possible to have two public class in one single java file.

Comment: They are all in separate files.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `Registry` nor what the problem actually is.

Comment: The classes are mixed up. Block is Item and vice versa. Or why you have a Block in the Block class? The Block is a block, not  a container for another block, no?

Comment: Yes fine, if all classes are in separate files. But I agree with Zhuinden, what is the purpose of having `Registry` class?

Comment: Why not use some kind of updatehandler where you fire updates and changes?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when `ItemDirt` is constructed and assigned to `Registry.itemDirt`, its constructor already uses `Registry.blockDirt`, although it has not been initialized and is still `null` at that point of time.

This is a typcial problem that happens when objects try to prematurely grab alien objects at construction time. Usually, a constructor should never 'reach' outside and grab other objects that may or may not exist at that point of time.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no pretty way to break your vicious circle without some visible alterations to your code, but maybe something like this will be less ugly:

```
public class Registry() {
    public static ItemDirt itemDirt;
    public static BlockDirt blockDirt;

    static {
        itemDirt = new ItemDirt();
        blockDirt = new BlockDirt();
        itemDirt.setBlockDrop(blockDirt);
    }
}
```

Or some lazy initializations in your `set` methods. Your call.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to implement something similar to the [Mediator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern), but the real way to do this is not in the constructor, because you cannot be assured of the order of construction.

Instead, when you implement a business method, you call a Mediator, which then handles the inter-class communication.  Please read up on the Mediator Pattern before you go further, as it will provide some insight on how to do this better.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example of Mediator?

Comment: Please check the linked Wikipedia article.  Alternatively, instead of holding local references to other classes, just use `Registry.itemDirt` or `Registry.blockDirt` when your objects need to reference each other.

Comment: If I understood correctly, Mediator is "server" which sends and receives data from and to objects.

Comment: The mediator provides a "meeting point" if you will, which many objects know about, and call into.  This class then operates on a variety of different objects to perform the requested operation. It's not a great pattern IMO, but it's close to what you're trying with the Registry concept. The iOS AppDelegate often acts as a mediator class for iOS applications since it's accessible globally.